# Can't set user picture in Xubuntu 22.04

Tags: user-profile

Apparently, using .face doesn't work anymore. I've also tried setting it through About me and through LightDM. Neither works, either. The picture silhouette still shows on the log-in screen. I also get an error message in LightDM.

Any thoughts on how to make this work?

Comment: Why do you keep the error message secret? Please provide the error message so we don't need to guess what the error is.

Comment: Sorry. It's a message on LightDM -- an exclamation point next to the line that says "default user image:" LightDM does not have permission to read path /home/user (where user is my name. I didn't this is 20.04

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1418888/edit) your question to add this important information to the question body. Doing so will bump your question to the home page and more helpful folks will have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I won't say I have a good solution but I did manage to cobble together something that clumsily works. Here is the part of my bash script that runs in a loop over a set of users, with the user account name in the variable `unm` and where I have a bunch of image files pre-setup in a consistent naming scheme. It relies on having `crudini` installed.

The display manager login avatar per user is handled as:

```
cp avatar_$unm.png /var/lib/AccountsService/icons
touch /var/lib/AccountsService/users/$unm
crudini --set /var/lib/AccountsService/users/$unm User Icon "/var/lib/AccountsService/icons/avatar_$unm.png"
```

The display manager login background per user is handled as:

```
mkdir -p /var/lib/AccountsService/backgrounds
cp wallpaper_$unm.jpg /var/lib/AccountsService/backgrounds
crudini --set /var/lib/AccountsService/users/$unm org.freedesktop.DisplayManager.AccountsService BackgroundFile "'/var/lib/AccountsService/backgrounds/wallpaper_$unm.jpg'"
```

Note that these are independent of the equivalent settings that each user can make from inside their account. I'm not especially seeing that as a bad thing.

This is from one part of some (still minimal) stock setup scripts that I use for fresh installs. See the repository at [ubuntu_accounts_setup](https://gitlab.com/geraldew/ubuntu_accounts_setup)

Notably for this thread, see the file: set_avatars_users_xubuntu_2204.bash